# Подготовка данных для обучения нейронной сетью. Python

Tags: нейронные-сети, python-3.6, нормализация-данных, обработка-данных

Обучаю нейронную сеть.
У меня данные имеют различные ед. изм-я. Когда я обрабатываю их Standart Scaler, эта проблема решается. Но остается другая - числа выходят из диапазона [-1;1]. Когда я применяю MinMax Scaler для решения этой проблемы, сбивается то, что было исправлено Standart Scaler-ом: дисперсия становится != 1, mu тоже не 0. Если опять применить Standart Scaler, то опять числа выйдут из диапазона. И т.д. Применять normalize/Normalizer, во-первых, не получится: он не приводит к нормальному с дисп=0, мю=1, а также не дает запоминать скелеры (это необходимо!). Как же решить эту проблему?

Comment: по-моему получить сразу и то и другое не получится. Или вы используете `MinMaxScaler` и получаете дисперсию == 1 или используете `StandardScaler` или `RobustScaler` и получаете числа в диапазоне `(-1, 1)`, но дисперсия не будет равна единице.

Comment: А обучать сеть вне диапазона [-1;1] чем-то грозит?

Comment: насколько мне известно, нет.